# How to avoid collision in hashtable?

Tags: c++, hash

So recently I have been solving a problem in codeforces using hashing.
I have used linear chaining for ignoring collisions, my task is to register names in the database. If any name is registering for first time, I print OK!. if repeats for the second time, I have to put 2 at the end of the name and so on.
Here is my code:

```
#include <bits/stdc++.h>

using namespace std;

const int MAXSIZE = 1e6 + 5;

class HashTable
{
    list<string> *table;

public:
    HashTable(); // Constructor
    unsigned long long hashFunction(string key);
    unsigned long long getTablesize(unsigned long long hashIndex, string name);
    void insertItem(string name);
    void printTable();
};

HashTable::HashTable()
{
    table = new list<string>[MAXSIZE];
}

unsigned long long HashTable::hashFunction(string key)
{
    unsigned long long rslt{};
    for (unsigned long long i = 0; i < key.length(); i++)
    {
        rslt += key[i];
    }

    return rslt % MAXSIZE;
}

// unsigned long long HashTable::getTablesize(unsigned long long hashIndex, string name)
// {
//     unsigned long long rslt = 0;
//     for (auto x : table[hashIndex])
//     {
//         if (x == name)
//             rslt++;
//     }
//     return rslt;
// }

void HashTable::insertItem(string name)
{
    unsigned long long hashValue = hashFunction(name);
    unsigned long long nos = table[hashValue].size();

    if (nos > 0)
        cout << name << nos << endl;
    else
        cout << "OK" << endl;
    table[hashValue].push_back(name);
    return;
}

int main()
{
    HashTable HT;

    unsigned long long n;
    cin >> n;

    while (n--)
    {
        string name;
        cin >> name;

        HT.insertItem(name);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

So whenever i am giving a string "xoyd" it says OK if the name is being stored for the first time. The second time it prints xoyd1(1 to n) and so on. When I am giving "xozc", collision happens and it prints xozc2 afterwards. So what can I do actually?

Comment: You described what happens. What did you expect to happen instead?

Comment: I think you should check your ```hashFunction```. Hashing means an index value is calculated from the value that you want to put into your table. It may happen, that different names end up with the same hash value. Which actually could be the case for "xozc" and "xoyd". Fr instance if your hash function gives an integer value to your letters for instance such as a = 1, b = 2, c =3 and so forth you may end up with having both names the same hash value and hence both names are stored in the same location as if they were identical.

Comment: Collisions will happen (pigeonhole principle and all that). Your code has to work correctly (albeit slowly) even if everything is hashed to zero and goes into collisions.

Comment: you are looking for a perfect hash function https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Perfect_hash_function, however it is possibile only when the input is limited. If you want to deal unbounded input, you need to cope with collision.

Comment: @dratenik I expect it to avoid the collisions, like storing xoyd and xozc in the same index would always give me wrong answers. Say there are already 7 xoyd in the list and I want to register a new name "xozc" but output comes xozc8 as xoyd and xozc are facing collision problems and there are already seven xoyd available. If I run linear search to find out how many "xoyd" is in the list, as n is 10^5, worst case is that the complexity is O(n) and program becomes slow. So I kind of want something efficient which will handle these collisions.

Comment: The hash function points you to a bucket, you search the bucket. If in the face of collisions you would get wrong answers, you're doing it wrong. Collisions will happen (unless you can prove that your hash function will never produce one for your input data...). I suggest you read some introductory explanation to hashing. However the bucket doesn't have to be a linked list with linear search, if you're concerned about worst-case performance, you can make it a tree for O(log n) lookups (I think java does that in its implementation).